# TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3 - Again

Tags: python, typeerror

> line 3, in 
>       reduced_price=int(input("The initial price is : " ,age, "%"))
>   TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3 :

```py
age=int(input("The age of the customer is : "))
initial_price=float(input("The initial price est : "))
reduced_price=int(input("The reduced price is : " ,age, "%"))
print("The price after reduction is", initial_price-reduced_price, "$")
```

Comment: I'm unsure what you are intending to do on line 3. For `input()` you can only have one argument which is the text that it prints to the user. You have the `,age, "%"` there also which is causing the error. I'm not sure what you want to do with the age and %.

Comment: Hello @MyNameIsCaleb.
For age, I give you an example: if a 22 year old customer will have 22% reduction.

Comment: Thanks, I added a solution for you to fit those parameters with explanation in the comment lines.

Comment: Looks like in line 3 you want to use print instead of input

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix.

For line 3, you don't need input because you have all of the information you need from the user. All you need to do is do the math required which is to take the age and make it a percent, then multiple it by the price.

Then in the print line you can do the same reduction as before (but fixed a typo).

```py
# I changed this to float rather than int since we are dealing with floats
age = float(input("The age of the customer is : "))
initial_price=float(input("The initial price est : "))
# round(number, decimal_place) to make it a money amount rounded
# initial price * age/100 (age as a percent)
reduced_price=round((initial_price * (age/100)),2)
# this is an f string for Python 3.6+
print(f"The price after reduction is {initial_price-reduced_price}")
```

And in practice:

```py
>>> age = float(input("The age of the customer is : "))
The age of the customer is : 22
>>> initial_price=float(input("The initial price est : "))
The initial price est : 75
>>> reduced_price=round((initial_price * (age/100)),2)
>>> print(f"The price after reduction is {initial_price-reduced_price}")
The price after reduction is 58.5
```